# How to make button disable after one click using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a send Button, that contains 2 Api in it.
So, if the input box is empty then send the button is disabled.
Now i want 1 condition to work,
After giving Email-Id and click on save button, it must get disabled after one click.
If i edit again on input box then it must be enabled or it must be in disabled state.

Comment: Can you add the html code?

Comment: you need to use two variables for the same

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara so much is my html code

Comment: @PardeepJain Can you please help me how to do that please

Answer (score 0):

If you are uisng  **reactive forms** take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-validation-test).

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public form: FormGroup;
  public isThePreviousEmail: boolean;

  private previousEmail: string;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.isThePreviousEmail = true;
    this.buildForm();
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if (this.previousEmail) {
        this.isThePreviousEmail = value !== this.previousEmail;
      }
    });
  }

  public onSubmit(): void {
    this.previousEmail = this.form.value.email;
    this.isThePreviousEmail = false;
  }

  private buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]
    });
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    Email: <input formControlName="email">

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.get('email').invalid || !isThePreviousEmail">Submit</button>
</form>.
```

I'm using reacctive form validation to disable the submit button. And a boolean variable which becomes false when user edit the input field.

`[disabled]="form.get('email').invalid || !isThePreviousEmail"`

and i'm subscrbing to form value changes like this.

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
          if (this.previousEmail) {
            this.isThePreviousEmail = value !== this.previousEmail;
          }
});
```

And on the `onSubmit` method i'm setting the value to the previousEmail and making the `isThePreviousEmail` to false.

```
public onSubmit(): void {
    this.previousEmail = this.form.value.email;
    this.isThePreviousEmail = false;
  }
```

This might help you to take an idea.

Comment: No i am not using reactive forms, just using ngModel

Comment: If you use disabled in reactive forms you'll get a warning that you shouldn't do it. You should do it by patching the control.

Comment: @IngoBürk Does this happens even when disabling a **button**? which is not a **formControl**.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<button (click)="generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail)" class="btn pull-right otp" [disabled]="buttonDisabled">Some Button</button>

buttonDisabled: boolean = false; //class variable
generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail) {
    this.buttonDisabled = !this.buttonDisabled

    // TO DO

    // If any error/valdiation fails, again reset this.buttonDisabled = !this.buttonDisabled
}
```

Comment: Hai, sorry it doesnt work because i have already given condition in *ngIf for disabling untill email or sms input is empty

Comment: ngIf does not disable, it hides button.

Comment: <button (click)="generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail)" class="btn pull-right otp" *ngIf="isConfirmEmailOtp || isSms" [disabled]="buttonDisabled">Send OTP</button> here in this case, the button is disabled untill input is given to thoise fields

Comment: try this, If you want to hide than use ngIf   `<button (click)="generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail)" class="btn pull-right otp" [disabled]="buttonDisabled || !isConfirmEmailOtp || !isSms">Send OTP</button>`

Comment: even after giving input it is disabled

Comment: I have updated my comment check now. `[disabled]="buttonDisabled || !isConfirmEmailOtp || !isSms"`

Comment: here 3 conditions it is checking, if input field is empty then it is disabled, if input field has a value then it is enabled, so these 2 are working, but now one more i need that is after one click button must be disabled

Comment: have you added `this.buttonDisabled = !this.buttonDisabled` on top of function?

Comment: ya,   generateEmailOtp(enterSms, enterEmail) {
    this.buttonDisabled = !this.buttonDisabled;

Comment: no error, but even after entering in input field i get button disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML only for that :

```
<button
  #submitButton
  (click)="generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail); submitButton.disabled = true;"
  class="btn pull-right otp"
  *ngIf="isConfirmEmailOtp || isSms">Send OTP</button>
```

And to enable it again once the input changed :

```
<input
  class="form-control col-lg-12" 
  type="email" 
  [(ngModel)]="enterEmail"
  name="myEmail"
  #myEmail="ngModel"
  email
  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
  (input)="submitButton.disabled = false"
  #emailOTP>
```